# PHP - newest file from dir doesnt work

Tags: php, image, file, directory, wamp

I am using this script:

```
<?php

$path = "/cam/video/INDOOR/grabs/"; 
$sirka = "640";
$vyska = "480";

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    
$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;

  }
}

echo '<a href=';
print ($path);
print ($latest_filename);
echo ' target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px solid ; width: ';
print ($sirka);
echo 'px; height: ';
print ($vyska);
echo 'px;" src="';
print ($path);
print ($latest_filename);
echo '"</a> ';

?>
```

It should display the newest ptohot from $path 
$sirka is width atribute and $vyska is height atribute fot image

I am using actual version of WAMP but nothing happend :/ it used to work when i used old version. can you help me? thank you

//EDIT:

i found it

i added $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. to the $path

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cam/video/INDOOR/grabs/';
```

Comment: Explain `doesnot work` - you have errors? Blank page? Unexpected results?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script and see if it outputs any errors.

Comment: Blank page only,

this is error report

( ! ) Warning: dir(/cam/video/OUTDOOR/grabs/,/cam/video/OUTDOOR/grabs/): in C:\wamp\www\new\outdoor_big.php on line 11
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0008 251728 {main}( ) ..\outdoor_big.php:0
2 0.0009 253640 dir ( ) ..\outdoor_big.php:11

Comment: i found it

i added $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. to the $path


    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cam/video/INDOOR/grabs/'; 


thank you guys!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your issue, but if the webserver user has read access to `/cam/video/INDOOR/grabs/`, try:

```
array_multisort($times = array_map('filectime', $files = glob("$path/*.*")), SORT_DESC, $files);
$latest_ctime = $times[0];
$latest_filename = files[0];
```